# JavaScript: Array sorting optimization

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a JavaScript array with nested object for ex: `[{id:1, position: 1}, {id:2, position: 2}, {id:3, position: 3}, {id:4, position: 4}, {id:7, position: 7}, {id:5, position: 5},{id:6, position: 6}]`. This is just an example actually I have an array in my app having 100 of records. And I am trying to sort the array with JavaScript array sort method. Let say array name is myArray, so I am doing something like below:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.position- b.position;
});
```

It's working fine but it's freezing my browser. Is there any good optimized way to do the sorting.

Comment: Does this happen in every browser? How did you determine that this is what is causing the freeze?

Comment: If it is working, but freezes the browser, you got to set it in parts ( due to single-threadedness ) with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Does that data come from a request of some sort? If so, it would probably be better to have the server sort the data before transmitting it.

Comment: Try to add it to `setTimeout(sortFunction(){...}, 0)`.

Comment: Factors to freeze the browser would be: extremely long array, extremely deep nesting, or extremly complex sorting callback. From what you write, none of these seem to be the case. Maybe you need to give more details about your data and your sort callback.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47963/quick-sort-implementation-in-javascript-in-prototype-style Checkout quicksort... not sure if it would help for 100 records

Comment: Let me explain my issue in details! I have already one array and through some kind of real time updates I am getting a new object. So I need to push that new object to my array in correct position as per the position key. So I am just pushing it and then trying to sort the final array.

Comment: I just created an array of 100 elements like the one you have, then I sorted it with your function. It is really fast. You might want to check for problems elsewhere in your code.

Comment: For adding one item at the correct position it is more efficient to find that position in a linear search and than add it there.

Comment: Not sure but removing that line of codes make my application solid. And when I add that piece of codes it just hangs!!!

Comment: @DeepakBiswal I highly doubt that this would be causing any significant delay, is there any chance you could put together a JSfiddle so we can see it hang the browser?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal Are the positions consecutives or is there somehow a way to predict  the position value for a new object ?

Comment: To predict the new position also I need to loop through existing array and find out where the new object set as per the position property of the new object!

Comment: I don't understand.. what do you mean exaclty ?

Comment: Let say I have existing array like: `[{id:1, position: 1}, {id:2, position: 2}, {id:3, position: 3}, {id:4, position: 4},{id:6, position: 6}]`. So now I got a new object '{id:5, position: 5}' so I need to add just after position 4 object. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Yes that makes sense now, I'll try to write an answer.

Comment: So why don't you just use an Array to start and set the elements into their position?

Answer (score 1):

In one of your later comments, you mentioned that the data comes in bit by bit, rather than all at once. But `Array.prototype.sort()` has to rework the entire array every time, even though it is mostly already sorted; only a few elements are out of where they should be.

For a case like yours, I'd be tempted to go with an *insertion sort* instead of JavaScript's built-in sort method (which is usually a variant of *merge sort* or *quicksort*, depending on the engine). **Insertion sort isn't very good as a general-purpose sorting algorithm, but it's good when you just need to add a couple of items into an already-sorted array.** That's what you're doing here, so it sounds like a good fit.

Here's a basic implementation of the algorithm.

```
/**
 * Compare two items as though they were strings.
 *
 * This is like the default comparison for Array.prototype.sort()
 *
 * @param {*} a The first item
 * @param {*} b The second item
 *
 * @return -1 if a is less, 1 is b is less, 0 otherwise
 */
function compareStrings(a, b) {
    var sa = String(a),
        sb = String(b);

    if (sa < sb) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (sa > sb) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Insert a new item into a sorted array.
 *
 * The compareFunction callback function works as for the analogous argument
 * in Array.prototype.sort(). Leave unspecified to compare lexically.
 *
 * @param {Array}     data            A sorted array, into which to put this item
 * @param {*}         newItem         The item to add to the data.
 * @param {Function=} compareFunction Optional comparison function.
 */
function arrayInsert(data, newItem, compareFunction) {
    var stop = data.length,
        i = 0;

    compareFunction = compareFunction || compareStrings;
    while (i < stop) {
        if (compareFunction(newItem, data[i]) < 0) {
            data.splice(i, 0, newItem);
            return;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    // If we got this far, then this should be the last item.
    data.push(newItem);
}
```

The whole array still needs to be sorted once, when the page loads, and you shouldn't use insertion sort for that (it would be best if you get the server to send you already-sorted data, but if you can't do this, then use the normal `Array.prototype.sort` function instead). Then, when you get new data, call `arrayInsert(data, newItem, /* your comparison function */)` once for each of the new data items you get. This should speed things up.

If this is still too slow, then you can put your new data items into a queue, and add a short timer to the page. Every few milliseconds this timer checks the queue, and if there are any items waiting, it adds one of them to the array. This won't actually make things faster (in fact, it will make them a bit slower), but the page shouldn't freeze anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing and then sorting, I suggest to use binary search to define at which index you should insert your new object.

The following code has no overhead since there are no function calls.

Also there is a variable `iteration` which only serves as a witness, you can throw it away.

**I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/00qhcuc5/5/) of the following code**

Assuming that your `a` is ***already sorted*** and contains ***UNIQUE*** positions you can do this

```
// THIS SECTION IS ONLY THERE TO SUIT YOUR CONSTRAINTS (100 objects in a)
var a = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (i & 1) {
        a.push({ id: i, position: i }); // objects are pushed only if they position is odd
    }
}

// this means o.position (our new object) can have any even value, we know that it won't already exist in a
var o = {
    id: 2,
    position: 2
};
var start = 0,
    end = (a.length - 1),
    mid = end >>> 1,
    left,
    right;

var iterations = 0;

while (mid !== a.length - 1) {
    if (mid > 0) {
        leftIsMore = a[mid - 1].position > o.position;
    } else {
        leftIsMore = false;
    }

    rightIsLess = a[mid].position < o.position;

    if (!leftIsMore && !rightIsLess) {
        break;
    } else if (leftIsMore) {
        end = mid - 1;
    } else {
        start = mid + 1;
    }

    mid = (start + end) >>> 1;
    iterations++;
}

var index = mid;

if (index === a.length - 1) {
    a.push(o);
} else {
    a.splice(index, 0, o);
}

console.log(a, 'Number of iterations to insert: ', iterations);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can make your own implementations of sorting algorithms that are very efficient like QuickSort and MergeSort.

[In this interesting article](http://tbranyen.com/post/increasing-javascript-array-sorting-performance) you find a comparison between the javascript sort() and an implementation of MergeSort. I recommend you to read more about [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and find the one that it adapts more to your problem.

Comment: There is no need to optimize the built-in sort algorithm. It sorts hundreds of thousands of elements in a fraction of a second.